# How to wait for N number of async functions to finish in node.js so that I can do some work on all their combined results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Please look at the code below. the request module is this one(https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var urlArray = [];  // URL in this level
foo ("xyz.com", false);   
function crawl (url, finished) { 
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (finished == true) { return; }
        // do some work on body (including getting getting n number of new URLS from
        // the body) and set finished = true if we find what we are looking for.

        // for each new url urlArray.push(newURL);

        // for each new url call crawl(newurl, finished);  

        // Now How can I know when ALL these requests have finished? 
        // so that I can have a urlArray corresponding to this level of crawling tree and 
        // do some work before starting next level of crawl.

    });
}
```

Comment: Use control flows in async.js

Answer (score 0):

use Promises.
Check out the Q library (specifically I pointed to the methods you need):
Promise creation:
https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer

```
var promise = Q.defer();
doAsyncStuff(callbackOfAsync);
return promise.promise;

functioncallbackOfAsync(isSuccess){
   if(isSuccess){
        promise.resolve();
    }
    else{
        promise.reject();
    }
}
```

Wait for multiple promises:
https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-for-array-methods

```
Q.all([getFromDisk(), getFromCloud()]).done(function (values) {
    assert(values[0] === values[1]); // values[0] is fromDisk and values[1] is fromCloud
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, the following flow of logic should work for you, I have added comments to help it make sense to you:

```
var urlArray = [];  // URL in this level
var finished = false;

foo("xyz.com", false);

function start() {
    while (urlArray.length) {
        crawl(urlArray.pop());
    }
}

function crawl(url) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (finished) {
            return;
        }
        // 1. at this point, a given batch of crawls have all started
        // AND urlArray is empty.

        // 2. do some work on body (including getting getting n number of new URLS from
        // the body) and set finished = true if we find what we are looking for.


        // 3. for each new url urlArray.push(newURL);

        // 4. start crawling on new batch of URL set
        start();
    });
}
```

All the request callbacks will be executed after `start()` completes, this guarantees that `urlArray` will be empty then.

If processing of one crawl response indicates (by setting `finished = true;`) that what you're looking for has been found all other processing of responses will terminate as soon as they begin.

Otherwise, reponse is processed and a new batch of urls are set for crawling. You call `start()` to begin crawling each.

It would help you also (as suggested in the other answer) if you acquainted yourself with the concept of ***[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)***.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I guess you will need Promises. I assume you are using NodeJS.

```
function makeRequest (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err || response.statusCode !== 200)
        reject(err || body);
      else
        resolve(body);
    }
  })
}
```

this function returns a promise. You can use it this way:

```
var request = makeRequest('url.com');
request.then(function (urls) {
  // this is called if no error occured
  urls.forEach(function (url) {
   console.log (url);
  });
}, function (error) {
    // this is called on error
    console.log (error);
});
```

If you want to wait for multiple requests to be answered to perform an action, use `Promise.all`:

```
var requests = [makeRequest(url1), makeRequest(url2), makeRequest(url3)];

Promise.all(requests).then(function (data) {
 // everything is done
 console.log(data);
});
```

I didn't test the code, but I hope you get the idea.